# Diamond-shaped table

Tags: html, css

I need to code a table, that would:

- have diamond shape
- be scrollable
- buttons in it's lines would be clickable

The only solution I could come up with was to put the table to an iframe, cover it with a picture with the table header and try to simulate clicks and scrolling through javascript events. Is there any better solution?

Illustration:
[image: Illustration]

Comment: Cover it with a picture and add CSS `pointer-events:none` to the picture.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cover it with a picture and add CSS `pointer-events:none` to the picture.
Credit: [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol)